# Is it possible to assign a string as a parameter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, builder, flutter-listview

I am trying to go though this list of strings and get a box colored at each color, is it possible in any other way I am missing?

```
List<String> myColors = [
  "blue",
  "red",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple",
  "yellow",
  "pink",
  "black"
];
----------------------------------
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
              itemCount: myColors.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final currentColor = [myColors[index]];
                final coloring = "Colors.$currentColor";
                return Container(
                  height:30,
                  width: 160,
                  color: coloring,
                  child: Text(coloring),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

With the current API it is not possible to get the right 'Color' instance by just providing the name of the color. Your options are:

1. Have a look at libraries like [color](https://pub.dev/packages/color)
2. Provide a list of hex, argb or rgbo values or Color instances instead of names
3. Try to get a premade map which maps all color names to the corresponding values

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
List<Color> myColors = [
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.yellow,
  Colors.pink,
  Colors.black,
];
```

---

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
  itemCount: myColors.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final currentColor = myColors[index];
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      width: 160,
      color: currentColor,
      child: Text(currentColor.toString()),
    );
  },
),
```